# overlay_ expression functions with generated geometries

Tags: qgis, expression, overlay

I want to use an `overlay_` expression but not use the features' original geometries. Instead I want to use a generated geometry, e.g. their `end_point()`. The `overlay_` functions operate using the current layer's features though.

Is there any way to do that?